# Current sense resistor vs transimpedance amp vs hall effect current sensor for instrumentation?

Tags: current, current-measurement, instrumentation, current-sensing, transimpedance

I'm using a photomultiplier tube; this creates a current output relative to the number of photons incident to it, on the magnitude of microamps. So, I need a precise and accurate way of measuring very small currents - I've seen a number of ways this can be done (in the title), but they don't seem to be compared much, and they're often used to measure much much higher currents in, say, power supplies. If I wanted to measure these currents, would there be an obvious or preferred choice?

Comment: Transimpedance amplifiers and current sense resistors are not restricted to higher currents (quite the contrary for the first one). Could you please clarify why you considered that? We'd also welcome some numbers to define "precise and accurate" in more consistent ways.

Comment: What is the gain you have and gain & BW that you need?

Comment: Usually a PMT is used with a current sense resistor or a transimpedance amplifier. Choice comes down to bandwidth, gain and number of photons/s that need to be detected.